# Overpass API JSON output cannot be read by QGIS

Tags: qgis, json, overpass-api

My steps:
1.) Query Overpass API and download the JSON output by this URL

```
https://www.overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:json];node[route=bus];way[route=bus];relation[route=bus](52.5,13.3,52.5,13.4);out;
```

2.) Loading this JSON into QGIS

**Issue**: QGIS 3.x says, that this JSON cannot be read.

My ideal approach is to not use QuickOSM or other tools in between.

Do I miss any ETL from JSON output to QGIS?

Comment: How do you plan to use this data? The output to that query is regular JSON containing a list of relations (each containing a list of members), with no geometry info. QGIS can read GeoJSON files, but as far as I know it can't read generic JSON on its own. (I'm using 3.10.4) You'll probably have to massage your output into some other form, depending on what you want to do with it.

Comment: You can get GeoJSON via Overpass Turbo: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_turbo/GeoJSON

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution. The query URL was not complete and partly wrong.

Correct URL:

```
https://www.overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:json];(node[route=bus](52.5,13.3,52.5,13.4);way[route=bus](52.5,13.3,52.5,13.4);relation[route=bus](52.5,13.3,52.5,13.4););out;%3E;out;
```

Changes

1. Wrapping the geometries by () to create a union query
2. Adding the bounding box coordinates behind every geometry
3. Adding a second output parameter to define the output of the wrapped union query.

Next step:
[osmtogeojson](https://github.com/tyrasd/osmtogeojson) can convert JSON or osm.xml to GeoJSON

Result: GeoJSON file which can be interpreted by QGIS.